# iOS check key exist

Tags: ios, json

I need to check if a key exist in a id.

I have this :

```
id tab = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

I need to check if the key "name" exist, but nothing works..

I tried :

```
if([tab objectForKey:@"name"])

if([[tab objectForKey:@"name"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull null]])
```

etc.. but I've ALWAYS the error : [__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

What I have to do to check if the key exist before to get the value ?

Comment: check with valueForKey.

Comment: that happens maybe, because the `NSArray` has no such method like `–objectForKey:`, that method is a privilege of the e.g. `NSDictionary` class; see the `NSArray` class reference here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the data that you are receiving, NSJSONSerialization will give you one of three possible things:

nil - If there is any error during parsing, the result is nil.
An NSDictionary* - if the data is a JSON object, the result will be an NSDictionary*.
An NSArray* - if the data is a JSON array, the result will be an NSArray*. So you write:

```
id tab = [NSJSONSerialization ... ];
if (tab == nil)
{
    NSLog (@"There was an array, tab is nil");
}
else if ([tab isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    NSDictionary* tabDict = tab;
    // ... Do stuff with tabDict. Don't touch tab anymore. 
}
else if ([tab isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    NSArray* tabArray = tab;
    // ... Do stuff with tabArray. Don't touch tab anymore.
}
else
{
    NSLog (@"JSON parser went crazy. Report a bug to Apple");
}
```

You will need to figure out according to the documentation that you have what kind of JSON document the server is supposed to give you. But once you know that, just because you know that the server is *supposed* to send you a JSON object for example, that doesn't mean it *does* send you a JSON object. So you need to be careful and check the data you are receiving, to avoid your app from crashing if something unexpected happens.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast `tab` into `NSDictionary`.

```
NSDictionary *tab = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

or

```
NSArray *tab         = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];  
NSDictionary *dicTab = [tab objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

then check if key exists.

```
if([tab objectForKey:@"name"]){
    // Yes exists
}
```

**Note:** May be you need to cast it into `NSArray` before casting it to `NSDictionary`. It totally depends on your JSON reponse.

Comment: You missed the star ;) NSDictionary *tab = ... ;

Comment: That's not going to help, since the OP has an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: @gnasher729 what do you mean by OP?

Comment: Original poster - whoever posted the question at the start of the thread.

Comment: I mentioned in my answer about the array as well. I updated the answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Just remarking on this line of code:

```
if([[tab objectForKey:@"name"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull null]])
```

This is wrong. If you wanted to check whether the class of an object is the NSNull class, you would check

```
if([[tab objectForKey:@"name"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) // class not null
```

However, it is simpler and faster to check whether an object is an NSNull object by checking

```
if([tab objectForKey:@"name"] == [NSNull null])
```

This works because [NSNull null] is a singleton object. There will be only exactly one object of class NSNull, ever, and [NSNull null] will return that object. All NSNull objects are *the same* object.

You would receive an NSNull object if your JSON data contains a null value. Some servers never produce null values, some do and beginners' code crashes when that happens - so it is a good idea to check for null values.

The difference between an NSNull value and a nil value would be that in the first case, the server actually contained an entry "name": null, while in the second case there is just no entry with the key "name" at all.